# Issues when Updating from google services versions

Tags: java, android

I tried updating `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` to `com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0` but I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4.

I simply replaced the 3.0.0 version of the google services with version 3.1.0 and I had this error. Please can someone help, I tried a bunch of options but nothing succeeded I still get that error.

Answer (score 0):

In **build.gradle(Module:app)** change the versions of all google-services and firbase dependencies to **11.2.2** which is the latest version. E.g.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
}
```